# Is this statement true for a two variable continuous function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, partial-derivative

Let $f:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R $ be a continous function. Can the derivative $\dfrac {\partial^2f}{\partial x \partial y} $ exist without $\dfrac {\partial f}{\partial x}$ existing?

Comment: Sure. $f(x,y) := y+ 1/x,$ and consider the derivatives at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Or $f(x,y)=|x|$ .

Comment: But note that $\partial f/\partial y$ must exist

Comment: @MPW That's obvious.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 : For that matter, the answer to the original question is obvious. My point is that the order of the partials is important.

Comment: @stochasticboy321: Nope. $(0,0)$ isn’t in the domain of $f$, so it isn’t in the domain of any of the derivatives of $f$. Note that OP specified the domain as $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: If $f$ is a function of $x$ only, then  ${\partial f \over \partial y} = 0$ and hence ${\partial^2 f \over \partial x  \partial y} = 0$. Now choose the function of $x$ to be non differentiable.

Comment: Quite right, @all. Retracted.